# Does proving $Q^{(1)}(\mathcal{N}\otimes\mathcal{N})=Q^{(1)}(\mathcal{N})+Q^{(1)}(\mathcal{N})$ imply additivity for arbitrary $n$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I have been reading the proofs that are usually presented in order to proof the additivity of degradable and conjugate degradable channels, and they usually present that the coherent information is additive for two channel uses, i.e. $Q^{(1)}(\mathcal{N}\otimes\mathcal{N})=Q^{(1)}(\mathcal{N})+Q^{(1)}(\mathcal{N})$, and then immediately state that such thing implies that the quantum channel capacity is single-letter characterized.

My question is then, does proving that the channel coherent information to be additive for the two-channel use case imply that it is additive for larger $n$?

---

*[Cross-posted on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/28757/55)*